# Number of functions on n boolean inputs

Tags: probability

In an [online course](https://work.caltech.edu/homework/hw1.pdf) on Machine Learning, I came across this statement:

> Note that in this simple Boolean case, we can enumerate the entire input space (since
>   there are only $2^3$ = 8 distinct input vectors), and we can enumerate the set of all
>   possible target functions (there are only 
>   $ 2^{2^3}\ = 256 $ distinct Boolean function on 3
>   Boolean inputs)

How did we obtain the latter value?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Each of the $8$ distinct input vectors must map to $0$ or $1$ (that is, there are $2$ possibilities), but the result can be chosen for each input vector separately. Therefore there are $2^8$ ways to make these choices, and $2^8=256$.